# Why does Camunda attempt to execute a task listener in the wrong process engine?

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I have three Camunda engines using a shared database:

- [core-workflow](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/tree/master/core-workflow)
- [core-processes](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/tree/master/core-processes)
- [domain-hello-world](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/tree/master/domain-hello-world)

There is [starter_wrapper_process.bpmn](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/blob/master/core-workflow/src/main/resources/starter_wrapper_process.bpmn) in core-workflow. This process starts [WrapperProcess.bpmn](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/blob/master/core-processes/src/main/resources/WrapperProcess.bpmn) defined in core-processes. Finally, `WrapperProcess.bpmn` starts [DomainProcess.bpmn](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/blob/master/domain-hello-world/src/main/resources/DomainProcess.bpmn) from `domain-hello-world` engine.

When

1. `WrapperProcess.bpmn` starts `DomainProcess.bpmn` and
2. `DomainProcess.bpmn` completes (i. e. execution returns to `WrapperProcess.bpmn`),

I want to execute a certain piece of code before a domain process starts and after it ends.

This piece of code must be located in `core-processes` and the developers of `domain-hello-world` must be able to create and run their processes without ever thinking about this piece of code.

Therefore the activity `Start domain process` has two task listeners (tab `Listeners`) which are supposed to execute [DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/blob/master/core-processes/src/main/java/org/example/DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener.java) before the domain process starts and after it finishes.

[image: Image showing BPMN diagram in Camunda Modeler with the start and end task listener settings]

Since this listener is referenced from and defined in `core-processes` I assume that it will run in `core-processes` (provided all engines run in deployment-aware mode).

But it doesn't.

Let's say I launch all three engines and start `Starter Process` via the task list. In the console output I see `DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener.notify` which means that the start listener has been executed successfully.

Next, I go to the task list and complete the human task.

Now something unexpected happens: An incident occurs in the instance of `DomainProcess.bpmn` inside the `domain-hello-world` engine:

```
ENGINE-09008 Exception while instantiating class 'org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener': ENGINE-09017 Cannot load class 'org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener': org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener
```

[image: Incident in domain-hello-world engine]

Full stack trace is available [here](https://gist.github.com/dptij/144bc619c3c1c2262a1f1d7605384666).

At the bottom of it, you see a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ClassLoadingException: ENGINE-09017 Cannot load class 'org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener': org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EngineUtilLogger.classLoadingException(EngineUtilLogger.java:146)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:111)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ClassDelegateUtil.instantiateDelegate(ClassDelegateUtil.java:46)
    ... 187 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener
```

This is understandable -- `org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener` is defined in `core-processes` (not in `domain-hello-world`).

What I cannot understand is why it is `domain-hello-world` that tries to execute the task listener which is referenced in BPMN file that is located in `core-processes`. [DomainProcess](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/blob/master/domain-hello-world/src/main/resources/DomainProcess.bpmn) does not contain any task listeners and does not refer to `org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener`.

**How do I need to modify my code in order for `org.example.DomainProcessStartFinishTaskListener` to always be executed in `core-processes` (both before the domain process starts and after it ends)?**

**Update 1:** Setting `async-after` of the `Start domain process` as shown below activity did not help ([commit](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/commit/747bbc883d06fa529913d1e0ebbcb2087f17814e).

[image: Start domain process activity with async-after set to true]

**Update 2:** I tried to set `async-before` and `async-after` in all activities of all processes ([commit](https://github.com/dptij/task-listener-problem/commit/29205f578972244ef00dee24476b08a0f23e6d8d)). I am still getting the same error.

**Update 3:** As a workaround, I moved the end listener to an event after the call activity.

[image: Fragment of a new diagram]

Comment: You can use an event if you want to visualize the listener. However, on the sequence flow leaving the call activity you can also find a listener, Here it is just one event 'take'.

Comment: @rob2universe Adding a listener to the sequence flow would make this diagram unmaintainable. Nobody expects sequence flows to have listeners. If someone needs to debug this diagram, a listener on a sequence flow will make finding that bug much harder. I think there is only one case where adding listeners to seq. flows makes sense -- if you want to torture the maintainers.

Comment: If spotting listener is a challenge then you may  want have a look at https://emsbach.medium.com/the-best-free-plugins-for-camundas-bpmn-2-modeler-14eee0c9fdd2, esp. the Property info plugin. This makes it quite easy to spot all 'hidden' things, also data mappings, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs if an execution originates and runs in wrong class loader (here the domain process).
a) make sure you process engines are configured as deployment aware
b) if this does not suffice, try changing the async before on the end event of the domain process to async after
c) a workaround would be to set async after on the call activity and change the end listen on the call activity to a take listener on the subsequent sequence flow.

Comment: The execution listener is executed before the async after. Setting this flag will only help if the listener is also changed into a take listener on the outgoing sequence flow